# Can't upload a file to AWS S3 using OctoberCMS

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm using Builder plugin to upload images, and I'm getting this error:

```
"Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found"
```

Has anyone encountered this?

Thanks!

Comment: According to the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#driver-prerequisites) that requires you to install `league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the required package

> composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3

And If you already installed it, Make sure you are installing to the right folder. check your application vendor folder and make sure the package is installed in it.